# Adjacency matrix and changing order of vertices

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I'm having trouble seeing the permuting of rows and columns when a vertex order is changed:
The definition given:
Let $G$ be a graph with an ordered listing of vertices $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$.
The adjacency matrix of $G$ is the $n\times n$ matrix $A = [a_{ij}]$ with
$$a_{ij} = \#\text{edges connecting $v_i$ and $v_j$.}$$
The entries $a_{ij}$ depend on the order in which the vertices have been numbered.
**Changing the vertex order corresponds to permuting rows and columns.**
I'm given these graphs (left one is the first graph and second is the vertex $v_2$ and $v_3$ swapped:
[image]

The adjacency matrices are
$$A_1 = \begin{pmatrix}0 && 2 && 0 \\ 2 && 0 && 1\\ 0 && 1 && 1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$A_2 = \begin{pmatrix}0 && 0 && 2\\ 0 && 1 && 1 \\2 && 1 && 0\end{pmatrix}$$

I can't see the "permuting" of rows/columns here.
I see some values do swap around once (which makes sense), but it looks like we also permuted the main diagonal as well.
I want to try and understand this so I can try to understand the general case ($|V| = n$, and we swap say vertices $v_1,v_4,v_7$ around).

Comment: $A_2$ is the result of swapping the second and third rows and then the second and third columns of $A_1$. I think it's hard to see this in one go though. It might help to write down the 'intermediate step' of $A_1$ with just the second and third rows swapped.

Comment: Ah. Btw, swapping in the order of columns then rows is the same right? Since it's a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Yes, in fact even if it wasn't a symmetric matrix you'd get the same result doing the swaps in the other order

Answer (score 1):

As aPaulT stated previously, this is a joint swap of the 2nd and 3rd rows, then columns (in either order). This can be represented by left- and right-multiplication of the adjacency matrix by appropriate permutation matrices.

Let $P$ be a left-multiplication permutation matrix (row-swapping). $P^T$ is therefore the right-multiplication permutation matrix (col-swap) with the same ordering as $P$:

$P = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&1&0 \end{bmatrix}$

In this case, $P$ is equal to $P^T$ exactly; however, it is not hard to find an example of where this is not the case.

To produce the adjacency matrix of the node-swapped graph $A'$, perform the following operation:

$A' = PAP^T$